# When I received BusyBox error in linux

Tags: linux

When I restart my chaletos linux machine I got an error like BusyBox and not booting further, so shall I use this following command? fsck /dev/sda1 -y and say exit.

Comment: "an error like BusyBox" means nothing. Please post the actual verbatim output. You might also see if `/var/log/syslog` shows anything helpful, and post that section. Why would you think the file-system needs any repair ? Assuming it previously worked, what changes have been made since then ?

Comment: What you likely see is the banner message printed by the busybox shell when it starts. It may be that a busybox shell was started by your initramfs early in the boot process because it was unable to find or mount the root file system. And then it starts an interactive shell for you to try and fix the problem by hand. The error if any will be above that banner message. We can't help you further if we don't know what error you get.

Comment: Please DO NOT run the `fsck` command at this point